# Laravel's php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an odd question. I'm currently away at college and have been using some of my free time to work on some projects I have. If I run `php artisan serve` run on the college wifi network would people be able to go to localhost:8000 on their computers and view the website?

Comment: ofcourse not.  localhost works with or without internet connection.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I forgot localhost works without an internet connection...

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3):

localhost working only on current pc but if you want share your college friend then use like that

> find your current lan ip address

```
php artisan serve --host --port

php artisan serve --host=192.168.2.10

php artisan serve --host=192.168.2.10 --port=8000
```

Answer (score 1):

In laravel,Port listening on localhost:8000 but it is not available other PC if you want to share your site you need to send your ip address with your friends and your website should be running on your pc then your friends can see yuor website/application using IP:8000.